# case insensitive search in sequelize

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I want to search a user by it's email. Is there a way to ignore the case and search the user?
If the user in DB has email `abc@gmail.com`, then even if i give `where{email:ABc@gmail.com}}` should fetch me the user.

Current Query

```
User.findOne({ where: { email }, include: [...eagerModels] });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `Op.iLike`:

```
User.findOne({ where: { email: { [Op.iLike]: email } }, include: [...eagerModels] });
```

Comment: The question is about case insensitive search. You are doing case sensitive search.

Comment: The case-sensitive search operator is `Op.like` and not the `Op.iLike`

Answer (score 0):

Use `%like%` query for that. Sequelize uses Symbol operators by default to minimize the risk of operators injected in the query; it's advised to use Symbol operators going forward.

```
    const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
    const Op = Sequelize.Op;

    let data = await User.findAll({
      where: {
        name: {
          [Op.like]: '%abc@gmail.com%'
        }
      }
    });
```

Comment: Doesn't seem like it is doing a case insensitive search.

Answer (score 0):

Use `%iLike%` for searching case insensitive items on sequelize. Take note of the % to search from with side of the item as shown here...

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const Op = Sequelize.Op;

let data = await User.findAll({
  where: {
    name: {
      [Op.ilike]: '%abc@gmail.com%'
    }
  }
});
```

> NOTE: This only works on Postgres.

[Reference](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/model-querying-basics/#operators)

Comment: Can you offer an explanation on how your answer solves the question and also how it differentiates from previous answers? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: @DJSDev I have provided a more clarity to my answer